# Build server/shared assemblies: mapped drive or UNC?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When reading about build servers and sharing assemblies on the network (for assembly references in projects), I have always read that the preferred way to do this is to designate a drive letter, and use a login script to map the same drive letter on all development machines.

It seems as though there was some reason that a drive letter is favored over a UNC path, but I cannot remember why.  Can anyone remind me why I should favor a mapped drive over a UNC path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the drive letter so the debug symbols actually work.

Comment: That sounds like good information, could I get you to elaborate on the issue a little bit?

Comment: Both managed and unmanaged PDBs store complete paths to their referenced source code locations.  I don't remember what the exact issue is, I think the debugger will load PDBs just fine, but refuses to match up source symbols when the referenced source locations contains a UNC path.